# XCode, Unit Tests and Implementation Files

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, octest

I finally decided to add some unit tests to my simple iPhone application.  There is one thing that is kind of annoying and that is to have to include all dependencies in the test bundle.

But, maybe I'm doing it wrong..  Do I really need to add all my dependencies (implementation files, frameworks) to the test bundle for everything I need to test?

It's annoying but still simple when I add tests after the fact to just compile, add missing dependency, compile, etc... until the test passes.  But what if I did this test-first as I probably should have done in the first place?  My test bundle would have all of the dependencies setup then when I go to implement this in the actual app bundle, I'd have to make sure I add all of the dependencies so that the app doesn't crash.  So here I have a scenerio where my tests all pass, but the main app crashes because of a missing implementation file (or whatever).  I guess I can be diligent and remember to add them as they are created, but... I tend to forget things.

Would application tests work here?

So I'm curious to know how others iterate over this process?  Is there a better way?  Can I somehow link to the main app bundle?